# Verifying Law of total variance

Tags: distributions, variance

Hi I was trying to verify law of total variance, by creating 3 groups from a random sample of a standard normal. Can some tell me if my understanding or the code is wrong?

The Result is not ~ 1 which is the variance of a standard normal.

```
import scipy

# get 1000 random numbers from a normal dist. 
# So Variance is ~ 1
nums = scipy.randn(1000)

# split into 3 groups of (1,1,998)
g1=nums[0]
g2=nums[-1]
g3=nums[1:-1]

# calculate group means
group_means = [g1,g2,sum(g3)/len(g3)]

# calculate Var( E(Y|X))
V_EG = scipy.var(group_means)

# calculate group variances
group_variances=[scipy.var(g1),scipy.var(g2),scipy.var(g3)]

# calculate E( Var(Y|X))
E_VG = sum(group_variances)/len(group_variances)

print E_VG + V_EG
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the LTV in this context? How do you define $X$?

Comment: Y and X are the random variables. Y comes from a standard normal, X is discrete and denotes the groups. Marginal Variance of Y is 1.

Comment: Sorry, this description does not fit the experiment, where you generate  samples with different sizes. There is no $Y$ that corresponds to the output.

Comment: @Xi'an what do you mean by "There is no Y that corresponds to the output"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to completely define the conditional of $Y$ given $X$ and the marginal of $X$. For instance,$$Y|X=x\sim\mathcal {N}(\mu_x,1)\qquad X\sim p_x=\mathbb{P}(X=x)=1/3$$but this necessary definition clashes with the code above that produces 1, 1, and 998 samples when $X=1,2,3$, respectively, unless one sets$$p_1\approx p_2\approx 10^{-3}$$ In the later case you should correct the lines

`V_EG = scipy.var(group_means)`

and

`E_VG = sum(group_variances)/len(group_variances)`

towards a proper weighting of the three variances. Here is an illustration in R:

```
> x=rnorm(1e3)
> V_EG=((x[1]-mean(x))^2+(x[2]-mean(x))^2+998*(x[1e3]-mean(x))^2)/1e3
> E_VG=998*var(x[3:1e3])/1e3 #zero variance for one-point samples
> E_VG+V_EG #close to 1
[1] 0.9274475
```

using the estimated weights$$(10^{-3},10^{-3},998\,10^{-3})$$